# Reporting tweet or account using a C program

Tags: c, twitter, webbrowser-control

Using C on Windows, I can open a browser by running

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  system("start https://twitter.com");
}
```

But what if I want more than that, specifically reporting a tweet or an account **using C.** (or Python if no choice)

I have tried also Twitter API on Python (`tweepy`), that only can do like tweeting or liking a tweet etc.. but still unable to report tweets.

I would like to be able to do this via C program:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for reporting Tweets at this time.